# Difference between casting to an interface type and simple declaration with type

Tags: typescript, interface

I was reading about [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) in typescript and came across the following.

An interface named `Square` is defined as follows:

```
interface Square {
     width: number
}
```

Then a variable named `square` is declared by typecasting an object literat into `Square` type:

```
let square = <Square>{}
```

I tried printing `square` and `typeof square` which as expected gives `{}` and `object`. But I could not differentiate the above `square` definition from the following:

```
let sq: Square = {}
```

Here typescript throws an error saying the property `width` is missing from `sq`. How is this different from the casting syntax above? Here is also the [snippet from typescript-playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Square%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20square%20%3D%20%3CSquare%3E%7B%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log(square%2C%20typeof%20square)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20sq%3A%20Square%20%3D%20%7B%7D).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type assertions force the  compiler to accept things that are not type safe. So when you are using a type assertion the compiler will accept that `{}` is a `Square` even though it obviously does not conform to the interface.

When you annotate the variable explicitly, `let sq: Square` the type is determined by the annotation and the assignment will be strictly checked against this the variable type and you will get an error that `{}` doe not conform to the interface.

From a runtime perspective there is no difference between the two, in both cases what is left after compilation is the assignment of `{}` to a variable, types (in both annotation and type assertion) are completely erased by the compiler.

Generally you should avoid type assertions. Type assertions tell the compiler: "Ignore what you think is true I the programmer know  better!". There are cases where type assertions are necessary, but unless you are sure you need a type assertion you should avoid them, and try to fix things so the types are correct. Using type assertion you might get surprising results. For example:

```
interface Square {
    width: number
}
let square = <Square>{}
square.width.toExponential() // runtime error, the type did not really reflect the runtime object

let sq:Square = {} // error here at compile time here 
sq.width.toExponential()
```

Comment: Could you share an example where type assertions are necessary?

Comment: @SuhailGupta I could not give a general rule, but for example they are sometimes necessary in generic functions where the compiler can't workout the types but you are reasonably sure you have it right. Or when you are in the process of initializing an object but you can't do it in one line and you need to first crete the object and you run some code immediately after that will finish the init. Or when you are doing `getElementById` and you know the true type of the html element: `document.getElementById("#text") as HTMLInputElement`.Generally when you feel you know better than the compiler.

Comment: Type assertion and casting are often used with inheritance, or when an object has multiple  interfaces. That way, you can write a  single function or loop that works for different types of object. In the answer above you see `getElementByID()`, this function works for all types of `HTMLElement`, regardless of what type they really are.